# Compare Number of Equal Elements in Tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, equality, tensor

I have two tensors of dimension 1000 * 1. I want to check how many of the 1000 elements are equal in the two tensors. I think I should be able to do this in one line like Numpy but couldn't find a similar function.

Comment: could you convert the tensors into numpy array and then do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `==` operator to check for equality and then sum the resulting tensor:

```
# Import torch and create dummy tensors
>>> import torch
>>> A = torch.randint(2, (10,))
>>> A
tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> B = torch.randint(2, (10,))
>>> B
tensor([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])

# Checking for number of equal values
>>> (A == B).sum()
tensor(3)
```

---

**Edit:**

`torch.eq` yields to the same result. So if you for some reason prefer that:

```
>>> torch.eq(A, B).sum()
tensor(3)
```

Comment: Is this vectorized? I mean I am fine it it isn't just asking to be conceptually clear with how this function does the job.

Comment: @Vivek So I guess it is. But to be really sure you'd probably need to check out the C++ implementation.

Comment: FYI: The Pycharm type checker complains about `(A==B).sum()` as it thinks the output of the comparison is a boolean. PyCharm does not raise an error for `torch.eq(A, B).sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

`equal_count = len((tensor_1.flatten() == tensor_2.flatten()).nonzero().flatten())`

should work.